# How to access phone internal storage during flashing?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, htc-one-x

I am flashing CM10 to my HTC One X.

I downloaded all necessary files and unlocked my boot loader.  I followed all steps on how to install this ROM, but I did one stupid thing.  I forgot to copy the CM10 zip file to my phone internal storage.

Below are the steps I followed, then I missed step 1.  How do I access my phone internal storage so that I can save the zip file, and continue flashing my phone?

> 1. Copy the CM10 ZIP file to your phone’s internal SD card.
> 2. On the PC, extract the Fasboot.zip. You will get a folder named Fastboot.
> 3. Extract the boot.img file from the cm10_endeavoru-ota-eng.noeri-028.zip file and place it into the
>      Fastboot folder.
> 4. Turn your phone off.
> 5. Boot to Fastboot Mode. Hold down the Volume Down and the Power buttons until the screen turns on to enter Bootloader Mode.
> 6. In Bootloader Mode, highlight Fastboot Mode using the Volume keys and select it by using the Power button.
> 7. Connect your phone to your PC via USB cable.
> 8. Open a command prompt on your PC and navigate it to the Fastboot folder.
> 9. In the command prompt, type fastboot devices to check if your device has successfully connected to your PC. Your phone’s serial number
>      should appear on the screen.
> 10. Flash the boot.img by typing the following in the command prompt: fastboot flash boot boot.img
> 11. Go back to your phone and select Bootloader to go back to the main Bootloader menu.
> 12. In Bootloader Mode, highlight Recovery using the Volume keys and select it by using the Power button to boot into ClockworkMod
>       Recovery.
> 13. Select Wipe data/factory reset > Yes.
> 14. Select Install ZIP from SD card > Choose ZIP from SD card > select the cm10_endeavoru-ota-eng.noeri-028.zip file > Yes.
> 15. Select Go back > Reboot system now.

Comment: Do you have the `adb` executable available, and can you access the recovery mode? You might be able to `adb push` the file then. You don't need the entire SDK for that, just the `adb` binary (`adb.exe` plus some `*.dll` files if you're on Windows) are fine.

Answer (score 2):

From the steps above, I think you already flash a clockworkmod recovery (boot.img)

1. HOLD volume down until the recovery shows up
2. Use the volume keys to select Mount
3. Select mount USB storage
4. Connect your phone to your PC
5. Copy the CM10 ZIP file to your phone’s internal SD card
6. Eject phone from PC and unmount USB storage
7. Select Wipe data/factory reset > Yes.
8. Select Install ZIP from SD card > Choose ZIP from SD card > select the cm10_endeavoru-ota-eng.noeri-028.zip file > Yes.
9. Select Go back > Reboot system now.

Comment: It's not working... nothing happens. The bootloader says it has entered USB mode, but nothing happens on the PC. Tried on 2 computers.

Comment: I had same issue on a TAB4 10.1 SM-T535. It seems the network operator Vodacom had changed the id of the tablet to be a wifi model (matissewifi) to throw off someone trying to flash a ROM to it. Anyway, to get it to boot into TWRP I just had to install the TWRP app from the play store, which has an option to boot into TWRP, the key combinations never worked for me. I also flashed `CF-Auto-Root` to the device to install SuperSU, which might have allowed the TWRP app with ROot access to boot into recovery mode.